# Define SWIG typemaps once for multiple argument pairs

Tags: java, swig

I've successfully mapped a buffer-pointer/buffer-length pair to a ByteBuffer using a `%typemap` specific to the types and names of the two arguments.

How can I do the same, for multiple pairs of arguments in the same method, without a near-redundant copy of the typemaps, *and* without matching only by type?

**DETAILS**

For example, with these typemaps:

```
%typemap(jni) (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen ) "jobject"
%typemap(jtype) (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen) "java.nio.ByteBuffer"
%typemap(jstype) (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen) "java.nio.ByteBuffer"
%typemap(javain) (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen) 
"$javainput"
%typemap(javaout) (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen) {
    return $jnicall;
}
%typemap(in) (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen) {
    $1 = jenv->GetDirectBufferAddress($input);
    $2 = (long)(jenv->GetDirectBufferCapacity($input));
}
```

I can SWIG a C++ method like:

```
int32_t getArrayData( void * outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen );
```

Into a Java binding like:

```
public int getArrayData( java.nio.ByteBuffer outBuffer ) { ...}
```

But now I want to SWIG one C++ method to take two argument pairs:

```
int32_t getArrayData( void * outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen,
    void * outBuffer1, int32_t bufferLen1 );
```

And get in Java:

```
public int getArrayData( java.nio.ByteBuffer outBuffer,
   java.nio.ByteBuffer outBuffer1 ) {
```

Without:

- Copying all the `%typemaps` above and adding a "1" at the end of each argument name.
- Matching all `void*`/`int32_t` argument pairs, by removing all the argument names from the `%typemaps` above.
- Running a preprocessor on the *.i file.

Is this feasible in SWIG?

Comment: `%apply (void *outBuffer1, int32_t bufferLen1) { (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen) };` See [11.1.4 Reusing typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn6) and [11.2.3 Copying a typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn13).

Comment: I just realised that it should be the other way around, i.e. `%apply (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen) { (void *outBuffer1, int32_t bufferLen1) };`  This will copy all typemaps that exist for `(void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen)` to `(void *outBuffer1, int32_t bufferLen1)`.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Perfect. I tried it, and it worked. Your comments are the answer. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. And thanks for including the links. The second has a buffer/length typemap copy similar to this question.

Comment: Normally what I do is give the typemap a generic name, all in caps and then %apply the typemap everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in the SWIG manual in [11.1.4 Reusing typemaps](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn6) and [11.2.3 Copying a typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn13) you can easily duplicate an existing (multi-argument) typemap for other signatures or types using `%apply`.  In your case you probably need

```
%apply (void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen) { (void *outBuffer1, int32_t bufferLen1) };
```

to copy all typemaps that exist for `(void *outBuffer, int32_t bufferLen)` to `(void *outBuffer1, int32_t bufferLen1)`.